# Error with using enquo for creating function with ddplyr

Tags: r, function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z48fD.png)

I have the data above, i want to aggregate some variables on the basis of mean of SalesInThousand Variable.

I am creating a function and running it in a loop so that i don't have repetitively.

Here is what i am doing:

```
vars <- factor(names(Marketing %>% 
    select(-MarketID , -LocationID ,
            -AgeOfStore , -SalesInThousands)))

function1 <- function(x){



Sales_Aggregate <- Marketing %>% 
group_by(x) %>% 
summarise(sales_mean = mean(SalesInThousands))


}


function1(Marketing$MarketSize)

for(i in vars){



print(paste('Sales Aggregate by' , i))


print(function1(i))
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
>     Column `x` is unknown

When i try this:

```
testFunction <- function(Marketing , x) {


x <- enquo(x)


 df %>%

group_by(!! x) %>%
summarize(mean.Petal.Width = mean(Petal.Width))

testFunction(x = 'MarketSize')
```

I get this error:

> Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
>     no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"

I am unable to figure out what i am doing wrong.

I am new to R and creating functions so need help.

Thanks in advance

Abhik

Answer (score 0):

The function arguments should match the ones inside the function i.e. if the argument of the data is 'df', it should be the same inside the function as well

```
testFunction <- function(df , x) {
 x <- enquo(x)
 df %>%
   group_by(!! x) %>%
   summarize(mean.Petal.Width = mean(Petal.Width))
}

testFunction(iris, Species)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#    Species mean.Petal.Width
#      <fctr>            <dbl>
#1     setosa            0.246
#2 versicolor            1.326
#3  virginica            2.026
```

---

If we need to aggregate multiple variables, then use the `summarise_at` or `summarise_all`

```
testFunction <- function(df , varS, x) {
 x <- enquo(x)
 df %>%
   group_by(!! x) %>%
   summarize_at(vars(varS), funs(mean = mean(.)))
}

nm1 <- names(iris)[1:3]
testFunction(iris, nm1, Species)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#     Species Sepal.Length_mean Sepal.Width_mean Petal.Length_mean
#      <fctr>             <dbl>            <dbl>             <dbl>
#1     setosa             5.006            3.428             1.462
#2 versicolor             5.936            2.770             4.260
#3  virginica             6.588            2.974             5.552
```

Comment: Thanks for the help its working, I stating the df in my function because i want to put this function in a loop. how can i do it now for vars variable.

Comment: @ABHIKARORA  You don't need a loop.  Instead, you can use `summarise_at` or `summarise_all` for multiple variables.  I updated the  post

Comment: in the above image in my question there is this df called marketing and i want to use some columns in this loop:       for(i in vars){
  
  print(paste('Sales Aggregate by' , i))
  print(testFunction(df = Marketing , i))
} I have assigned the column to variable vars <- names(Marketing %>% 
        select(-MarketID , -LocationID ,
                -AgeOfStore , -SalesInThousands , -MarketSize)).  I want to use the testfunction function in the loop.

Comment: @ABHIKARORA  Based on what you mentioned, you don't need a loop.  Please look at the update I showed

Comment: @ akrun i think i am not able to explain myself clearly i need multiple variables in group_by, summarize statement needs to be the same i guess.

Comment: @ABHIKARORA  Based on the dataset u showed in the image and the code u are using, it is the same grouping variable.  Please update your post with the dput of example and also the expected output