# Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : Column is unknown

Tags: r, function, group-by, dplyr, quotes

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
df <- data.frame (
  age = rep(c("40-44", "45-49", "50-54", "55-59", "60-64"),4),
  dep = rep(c("Dep1", "Dep2", "Dep3", "Dep4", "Dep5"),4),
  ethnic = rep(c(rep("M",5),rep("NM",5)),2),
  gender = c(rep("M",10), rep("F",10))
)
```

I am trying to generate descriptive statistics for a number of similar dataframes, all of which come from different sources, so I can compare.

I am running the following code to get the count and proportion for sex, gender, ethnicity, age, and sex + ethnicity as a function, which I can apply to multiple datasets

```
Dems_fun <- function(data, sex, eth, dep, age) {

  Fun <- function(data, ...) {
    group_var <- quos(...)

    data %>% 
      group_by(!!! group_var) %>%
      summarise (n = n()) %>%
      mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>%
      unite(dem, !!! group_var, sep = "_", remove = T)
  }

  Sex <- Fun(data, sex)
  Sex_eth <- Fun(data, sex, eth) 
  Eth <- Fun(data, eth)
  Dep <- Fun(data, dep)
  Age <- Fun(data, age)

  Dems <- rbind(Sex, Sex_eth, Eth, Dep, Age)
  colnames(Dems) <- c("Category", "count", "percentage")
  return(Dems)
}
```

When I run this function

```
test <- Dems_fun(df, gender, ethnic, dep, age)
```

I get the following error message:

> Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : Column `sex` is unknown

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

I have seen this similar question [Error with using enquo for creating function with ddplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524630/error-with-using-enquo-for-creating-function-with-ddplyr), but I can't tell if the same errors apply to my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you're missing is you need to `enquo` the function's column names, and then unquote (`!!`) them when you use them as function arguments later on. So you'll make `age_var <- enquo(age)` and then refer back to that with `!!age_var` when you call `Fun`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame (
  age = rep(c("40-44", "45-49", "50-54", "55-59", "60-64"),4),
  dep = rep(c("Dep1", "Dep2", "Dep3", "Dep4", "Dep5"),4),
  ethnic = rep(c(rep("M",5),rep("NM",5)),2),
  gender = c(rep("M",10), rep("F",10))
)

Dems_fun <- function(data, sex, eth, dep, age) {
  # enquo all these variables
  sex_var <- enquo(sex)
  eth_var <- enquo(eth)
  dep_var <- enquo(dep)
  age_var <- enquo(age)

  Fun <- function(data, ...) {
    group_var <- quos(...)

    data %>% 
      group_by(!!! group_var) %>%
      summarise (n = n()) %>%
      mutate(freq = n / sum(n)) %>%
      unite(dem, !!! group_var, sep = "_", remove = T)
  }

  # unquote all these variables
  Sex <- Fun(data, !!sex_var)
  Sex_eth <- Fun(data, !!sex_var, !!eth_var) 
  Eth <- Fun(data, !!eth_var)
  Dep <- Fun(data, !!dep_var)
  Age <- Fun(data, !!age_var)

  Dems <- rbind(Sex, Sex_eth, Eth, Dep, Age)
  colnames(Dems) <- c("Category", "count", "percentage")
  return(Dems)
}

Dems_fun(df, gender, ethnic, dep, age)
#> # A tibble: 18 x 3
#>    Category count percentage
#>    <chr>    <int>      <dbl>
#>  1 F           10        0.5
#>  2 M           10        0.5
#>  3 F_M          5        0.5
#>  4 F_NM         5        0.5
#>  5 M_M          5        0.5
#>  6 M_NM         5        0.5
#>  7 M           10        0.5
#>  8 NM          10        0.5
#>  9 Dep1         4        0.2
#> 10 Dep2         4        0.2
#> 11 Dep3         4        0.2
#> 12 Dep4         4        0.2
#> 13 Dep5         4        0.2
#> 14 40-44        4        0.2
#> 15 45-49        4        0.2
#> 16 50-54        4        0.2
#> 17 55-59        4        0.2
#> 18 60-64        4        0.2
```

Created on 2018-05-30 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Legend. Thanks heaps :-)